# Grunt.js grunt-contrib-watch event not firing grunt.task.run

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I have a Grunt.js file which utilises "grunt-contrib-watch" and "grunt-exec", the reason for this is some custom functionality I want to utilise the handlebars precompiler in a unique way.

The code:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        watch: {
            src: {
                files: ['**/*.hbs']
            }
        },
        exec: {
            preCompileTemplate: {
                cmd: function(inputFile) {

                    grunt.log.writeln('DERP DERP' + inputFile);

                }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-exec');

    grunt.event.on('watch', function(action, filepath, target) {
        grunt.task.run('exec:preCompileTemplate:' + filepath);
        grunt.log.writeln('-------> ' + filepath);
        grunt.log.writeln('-------> ' + target);
    });

}
```

The problem I'm having when running `grunt watch` and then change a .hbs file, the 2 `grunt.log.writeln` with `------>` echo out to the console as expected.

The problem is `grunt.task.run` doesn't seem to ever run as the console log with `DERP DERP DERP` in it never appears.

Am I not able to run a task from within grunt-contrib-watcher? Am I doing this incorrectly?

Comment: See [Why is grunt.task.run not called in the grunt.event.on("watch") handler?](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch/issues/65)

Comment: You could have `grunt.event.on` for the watch event reconfigure the `src` option of your `watch` task every time it triggers and use the `spawn: false` option. An example of usage described __[here](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch#compiling-files-as-needed)__.

Comment: miqid - I used your solution, that spawn option is nice. Want to put it as an answer so I can put it as a solution for people who find this page?

Answer (score 0):

I was just trying to upload some files whenever they changed, but between you and miqid and plenty of reading shama's comments there, I did find a way to do it.  I think it should be what you were looking for as well,

```
var watched_files = 'src/**/*';
var my_command = 'echo ';
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    watch: {
      scripts: {
        files: watched_files,
        tasks: ['exec:whatever'],
        options: {
          spawn: false,
        },
      },
    },
    exec: {
      whatever: {
        cmd: function() {
          var fn = this.config.get('exec.current_file');
          return my_command + '"' + fn + '"';
        }
      },
    },
  });
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-exec');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

  grunt.event.on('watch', function(action, filepath) {
    grunt.config('exec.current_file', filepath);
  });
};
```

Now, I'm pretty new to grunt (like, learning it tonight), so <strike>maybe</strike> surely there's something clever or important I'm missing, but this gets me a way to run a curl command on a file that just changed by having `grunt watch` running.

Answer (score -1):

You need to configure your tasks in `grunt.initConfig`. You can see [more](http://gruntjs.com/sample-gruntfile)  in their official site.

```
grunt.initConfig({
    jshint: {
      files: ['Gruntfile.js', 'src/**/*.js', 'test/**/*.js'],
      options: {
        globals: {
          jQuery: true
        }
      }
    },
    watch: {
      files: ['<%= jshint.files %>'],
      tasks: ['jshint', 'yourAwasomeTask']
    }});
```